# Does mass of an object has different values in different directions

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I was studying " Force" (book Kleppner and kolenkow)  . I m unable to understand  a para which is saying  "if mass were different in different directions , acceleration would not be parallel to force and force and acceleration could not be related by a simple vector eq. Although the concept of mass having different values in different directions might sound absurd , but it  is not impossible "...   ??

Comment: Please add a question in text. Image-only questions are typically closed.

Comment: It is mathematically conceivable. However the authors continue "In fact, physicists have carried out very sensitive tests of this hypothesis, without ﬁnding any variation. So, we can treat mass as a scalar, i.e. a simple number, and write $\mathbf{F}=m\mathbf{a}$.
This is Newton’s second law of motion, which will underlie much of our subsequent discussion."

Comment: when you try to transform forces using Lorentz transformation while preserving $F=ma$  form you do get different transverse and Longitudinal mass, so it certainly isn't impossible, but this concept was later dropped in favor of better definition of force which describe force as $F=\frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}$, this definition gives same mass for different direction but results in acceleration not being parallel to force

Comment: You could imagine that $F_i=\sum_j m_{ij}a_j$ instead of $F_i = ma_i$. As a simple case, for example, you could have $F_x=(2.0 \text{ kg})a_x$ but $F_y=(2.1 \text{ kg})a_y$.

Answer (score 1):

Probably. In general Cayley-Klein spaces, the mass and the principle moments of inertia of a 3D rigid body are all parts of a 6-dimensional structure. In flat Euclidean space the mass is isotropic (the same in all directions). But in hyperbolic and elliptic spaces the translational mass behaves a bit like the rotational mass in that it depends on the distribution of mass in the rigid body and can vary in different directions.

Charles Gunn goes into the gory mathematical details in his thesis [here](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Geometry%2C-Kinematics%2C-and-Rigid-Body-Mechanics-in-Gunn/23fdc2990fd65b320bf1cd7e938d65d737d3be4d), but to make the idea slightly more plausible, we can consider the problem of a compact 2D rigid body moving on the surface of a giant frictionless sphere. Intuitively, and taking a close-up view, we can see that the body has two 'translational' degrees of freedom sliding across the surface of the sphere, and one 'rotational' degree of freedom spinning around its own centre. However, on a sphere, the 'translational'/'rotational' distinction breaks down, since each 'translation' is actually a rotation about a distant point 90 degrees away around the sphere. The 'translational mass' is actually the moment of inertia of the rigid body defined about this distant point.

In the limit as the sphere gets larger, these two points recede to infinity, and we find that the 'translational mass' is simply the moment of inertia of the body measured about a point at infinity. Since all parts of the body are equally distant from infinity in all directions, the distribution of mass within the rigid body has no effect and all the translational inertia terms are equal. The rotational inertia term is about the centre of the body, and for this one the distribution of mass *does* matter.

In 3D we get the same sort of effect, but now there are 3 rotational terms constituting the moment of inertia and 3 translational terms about axes that have been pushed away to infinity.

(See Remarks 191-193 and section 9.9.3 on pages 115-117 of Gunn's thesis.)

Since space where we happen to be in the universe is pretty flat, looking like an infinite Euclidean volume in all directions, any effects from the curvature are expected to be tiny - on the order of one over the radius of the universe. But in the presence of gravity, the distinction between 'translation' and 'rotation around some very distant point' becomes a bit more approximate, and the translational mass of extended bodies may turn out to be something a bit more complex than just a scalar number.